# Can't create a Bootstrap Switch (v2.0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some difficulty to use the plugin BootStrap Switch http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/
I inserted both files css and js correctly into my project but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap Switch 2.

---

Here my files loaded by BootStrapBundle which I retrieve at the top for the CSS and at the end of the page for the JS:

```
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

I try several way to create it:

```
<div class="make-switch" >
                        <input type="checkbox" id="switchBox" />
                    </div>

<input type="checkbox" class="switch-default" />
```

Try it on IE10 and Chrome... I really don't know what I am doing wrong...

---

### EDIT

Here my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hGKNv/

Comment: do you receive any error in the console?

Comment: It would be useful if u create a jsfiddle and can u post if u hv got any console errors from browser?

Comment: No errors! I checked it...

Comment: Have you tried switching the link of bootstrap js and jQuery? I had this kind of error before.

Comment: I will try that. But this is not logic because bootstrap switch is based on jquery so jquery has to be before bootstrap js
edit: it didn't work

Comment: I put the link of my jsfiddle

Comment: @QHero Please post the solution as an answer to this question and mark it as 'accepted'. According to Stack Overflow guidelines, please don't write 'solved' in the post title, instead marking an answer as 'accepted' is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my prob! :D

```
<input type="checkbox" class="" id="switchBox" />

$("#switchBox").bootstrapSwitch();
```

It is not indicated that we have to set the function bootstrapSwitch function to the control... Hope this post will be helpful for those who forgot like me to indicate that into their JS. Anyway cheers for trying helping me!